# how to register a receiver to catch launch

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I want to be able to catch intents issued for every application launched without reading the logs, since that is no longer available in late versions.
I am registering the receiver with:

```
registerReceiver(mAnyBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

where the filter has:

```
intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
```

but it doesn't trigger when i launch regular application. It works on regular actions like configuration changed and wifi state.

Answer (score 0):

Starting an activity does not involve sending a broadcast. Hence, you cannot register a broadcast receiver to find out when applications are launched.

Comment: How can i find out if an activity has been launched without parsing logs?